# Jquery Copy TD widths from 1 TR to another

Tags: jquery, clone

I have a tr like:

```
<tr><td><select multiple="multiple"></select></td><td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Delete" class="delRow" /></td></tr>
```

After cloning, the two rows will look like this:

```
<tr><td width="162px"></td><td><input disabled="disabled" type="text" /></td><td width="62px"></td></tr>
<tr display="none"><td><select multiple="multiple"></select></td><td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Delete" class="delRow" /></td></tr>
```

I'm going to insert a new row above that with the same number of fields but I'll be removing the `select` and the `button`, and I'll be hiding the original row (temporarily). With only the 1 new row visible, and it not having those two elements, the result is the whole table gets smaller in width.

I'm thinking I could somehow loop through the old $tr jquery variable's tds and copy their width to the clone. But I'm not sure exactly how. Here's what I'm working on:

```
$clone = $tr.clone();
$tr.children("td").each( function() {
    $(this).width(); // not sure how to set this.
}
$clone.find("input").prop("disabled",true); // disables the clone's "inputs"
$clone.find("select").remove(); // removes the "select".
$clone.find("input.delRow").remove(); // removes button from last td
```

I tried this solution, but it results in the clone's first TD having the same width as the entire original TR:

```
$clone.children().width( function(i, val) {
    return $tr.eq(i).width();
});
```

HTML now looks like:

```
<tr><td width="640px"></td><td><input disabled="disabled" type="text" /></td><td></td></tr>
<tr display="none"><td><select multiple="multiple"></select></td><td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Delete" class="delRow" /></td></tr>
```

Conclusion/Solution:

I found the reason why the obtained widths were incorrect before. My code was inside of a `slideToggle` function. So my source TR was already collapsed (hidden), and width is undefined for those hidden elements. I placed Amin's code outside of the slideToggle. Then I was able to use the `width` variable to make the new TR match the size of the original one.

Bad:

```
tr.slideToggle(100, function(){     
    $clone = $tr.clone();                           
    $clone.children().each(function(index) {
        $(this).width($tr.children().eq(index).width()); // fails to set width of cloned td's because $tr is now collapsed
    });
}
```

Good:

```
var width=[];
$tr.children().each(function(index) {
    width[index]=$(this).width(); // correctly sets width array values
}

tr.slideToggle(100, function(){     
    $clone = $tr.clone();                           
    $clone.children().each(function(index) {
        $(this).width(width[index]); // Correctly sets width of cloned td's because $tr's td values were saved to var width before the tr was collapsed by slideToggle
    });
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that your new tds are empty, try to put a `&nbsp;` inside of them

Comment: Thanks but that isn't the problem. I just need to know how I would copy the TD widths from one TR to another. That's really the question. I've updated my question title to reflect that.

Comment: loop through the existing tr set widths of its tds like $(this).css("width",$(this).width()); and then clone it.

Comment: @Sunand yes that would work but something about that kind of solution scares me. I'd prefer to leave the "real" table rows "liquid".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that `$tr` contains the tr with the desired td widths and `$clone` is the cloned tr, here's how you can get their tds widths and apply them to the new tr tds:

```
var width=[];
$tr.find('td').each(function(index){
    width[index]=$(this).width();
});
$clone.find('td').each(function(index){
    $(this).width(width[index]);
});
```

Comment: Could use $tr.children() instead of $tr.find('td'), if the tds are the direct descendants of $tr, right?

Comment: $(this).width() seems to be returning '0' for every td. I thought width() returned the computed width?

Comment: I just realized that var width is not passed into the each function. Does it need to be?

Comment: Yes. That doesn't work either. The issue is that the width var is getting set to `[0,0,0,0]`, or with .css `[0px,0px,0px,0px]`

Comment: can I ask how have you defined `$tr`?

Comment: `$tr = $(this).closest("tr");` console.log() shows it is a tr. It does get copied. But it has no width value set. I need to get the displayed width.

Comment: `.width()` returns the displayed width, but I have no idea why this is happening! it would help a lot if you could make a jsfiddle to let me work on it, otherwise there's just so many possibilities!

Comment: Hi Amin, after more struggling I believe I have found the reason. I am copying the width from within `$tr.slideToggle(100, function(){`. That is probably a noob mistake. Apparently, there is no width for hidden elements. When I get the width out before the slideToggle, it works fine.